# useContext not working for me with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am trying to implement `useContext` with Typescript, but unfortunately I'm getting an error

Code sample :

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

type IUser = {
  email: String;
  isAuthorized: boolean;
};
const user: IUser = { email: "", isAuthorized: false };
export const AppContext = createContext<IUser>(user);

const appcontextprodivder = (props: any) => {
  //const [appdata, setappdata] =  useState<IUser>(user);

  const [userstate, setuserstate] = useState<IUser>(user);

  const login = (useremail: string) => {
    setuserstate({ email: useremail, isAuthorized: true });
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setuserstate({ email: "", isAuthorized: false });
  };

  const updaateemail = (email: string) => {
    setuserstate({ ...userstate, email: "" });
  };

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ userstate, login, logout }}>
      {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default appcontextprodivder;
```

I'm getting this error:

> Type '{ userstate: IUser; login: (useremail: string) => void; logout: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IUser'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'userstate' does not exist in type 'IUser'

Code screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please, try this instead. The issues I noticed are

1. Wrong component name i.e `appcontextprovider` should not be in lowercase
2. The `IUser` was passed like the entire state, but that needed to be part of another state for login and logout to work

```js
import React, {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useState
} from "react";


type IUser = {
  email: String;
  isAuthorized: boolean;
};

type ContextType = {
  userstate: IUser;
  login: (arg: string) => void;
  logout: () => void
}


const user: IUser = {
  email: "",
  isAuthorized: false
};
export const AppContext = createContext < ContextType | null > (null);

const AppContextProvider = (props: any) => {
  //const [appdata, setappdata] =  useState<IUser>(user);
  const [userstate, setuserstate] = useState < IUser > (user);

  const login = (useremail: string) => {
    setuserstate({
      email: useremail,
      isAuthorized: true
    });
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setuserstate({
      email: "",
      isAuthorized: false
    });
  };

  const updaateemail = (email: string) => {
    setuserstate({ ...userstate,
      email: ""
    });
  };

  return ( <
    AppContext.Provider value = {
      {
        userstate,
        login,
        logout
      }
    } > {
      props.children
    } <
    /AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default AppContextProvider;
```